# Bootstrap 4 collapse внутри dropdown-menu и возвращение на уровень выше

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Есть небольшое bootstrap 4 меню с несколькими уровнями и `collapse` внутри:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();

  $(".collapse").toggleClass("show", "hide");
});


$('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).parents().next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass('show');
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).parents().next('.dropdown-menu');
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');


  $(this).parents('.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.menu-item .show').removeClass('show');
  });


  return false;
});


$('.dropdown-back').on('click', function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();

  $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');



  return false;

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-back btn btn-link">НАЗАД</a>

          <ul class="menu list-unstyled">
            <li class="menu-item">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                  Catalog 1
                </a>

                <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
              </div>

              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-back btn btn-link">НАЗАД</a>

                <div class="menu-col">
                  <div class="d-flex">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                      Sub Catalog 1
                    </a>

                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
                      >
                    </a>
                  </div>

                  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 2</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 3</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="menu-col">
                  <div class="d-flex">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                      Sub Catalog 2
                    </a>

                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
                      >
                    </a>
                  </div>

                  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 2</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 3</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 4</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 5</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Вопрос:**

1. Как разместить (сделать рабочим) `collapse` блок внутри `dropdown-menu` в Bootstrap 4 ?
2. Как правильно реализовать работу кнопки "назад" чтобы можно было закрывать не все меню, а лишь возвращаться на один уровень вверх?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил, как работает "НАЗАД". Что должен делать коллапс?

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".collapse").toggleClass("show", "hide");
});

$('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).parents().next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass('show');
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).parents().next('.dropdown-menu');
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');

  $(this).parents('.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.menu-item .show').removeClass('show');
  });
  return false;
});

$('.dropdown-back').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-back btn btn-link">НАЗАД</a>

          <ul class="menu list-unstyled">
            <li class="menu-item">
              <div class="d-flex">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                  Catalog 1
                </a>

                <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
              </div>

              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-back btn btn-link">НАЗАД</a>

                <div class="menu-col">
                  <div class="d-flex">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                      Sub Catalog 1
                    </a>

                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
                      >
                    </a>
                  </div>

                  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 2</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 3</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="menu-col">
                  <div class="d-flex">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                      Sub Catalog 2
                    </a>

                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
                      >
                    </a>
                  </div>

                  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 2</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 3</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 4</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">item 5</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: collapse при клике на определенную ссылку (точнее стрелку) должен открываться только соответствующий контент, а не все сразу! Расслабилась и не хочу думать сегодня ))))))))

Comment: @HamSter `$(".collapse").toggleClass("show", "hide");` открывает/закрывает *все* элементы `.collapse`

Comment: а нужен один соответствующий

Comment: Заработало! `$('.menu-col .btn').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $(this).closest('.menu-col').find('.collapse').toggleClass("show", "hide");
});`

Comment: Пробовала в реальном проекте почему-то не работает , но это уже мелочь